# Element cannot be located in parent view: Why im getting that error?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, erp, odoo-16

Hi I am trying to call a function from xml view using function tag. Im getting the next error and I dont get it: Element `'<function model="website.track" name="reconoce">' cannot be located in parent view.`
Any help would be apreciated.

XML code:

```
<odoo>
    <record id="vista_track" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">vista.Web</field>
        <field name="model">website.track</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="website.website_visitor_track_view_tree"></field> 
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            
               
                <field name="page_id" position="after">
                    <field name="partner_id"/>
                </field>
                <function model="website.track" name="reconoce">
                </function>
            
            
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

PYTHON code:

```
class visita(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'website.track'
    
    #prueba = fields.Char()
    partner_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name = 'mailing.contact',string='visitante')
    
    @api.model
    @api.depends("url")
    def reconoce(self):
        for a in self:
            var = a.url
            if "?" in var:
                try:
                    var2 = int(var[var.find('?')+1:var.find('%')])
                    a['partner_id'] = self.env['mailing.contact'].browse(var2)
                except:
                    a['partner_id'] = False
```

The thing is this code should call the function properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the function tag inside an inherited view arch, Odoo will try to find it in the parent view which is not what you want.

The [function](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/backend/data.html#function) tag can be used in data files. when evaluated Odoo will call the function on the corresponding model, we add it as a child `odoo` tag.

The function tag can't be used as a child of a tree view, you can check the tree view [rng](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/rng/tree_view.rng) file used to validate tree views